# How to generate URL from WebAPI method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Here's my WebAPI action..

```
public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
{

    [Route("api/auth/login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public object Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel loginViewModel)

    ...
```

How do I generate a URL inside a MVC view?

I've tried this...

```
@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Authentication", action=  "Login" })"
```

... but it says that `DefaultApi` doesn't exist.

Why does the method want a route name *and* route parameters?

How did they manage to make routing even more complicated than regular MVC?

What kind of web framework makes requesting a web page / API method / web service thing difficult? Its ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is because you are using attibute routing, so you need to declare the name of the route with the attribute Route, like:

```
[Route("api/auth/login", Name = "RouteName")]
```

And when you use **@Url.HttpRouteUrl**:

```
@Url.HttpRouteUrl("RouteName", new { controller = "Authentication", action=  "Login" })"
```